# how to reference none-amp-page to amphtml page and amp story page

Tags: amp-story, amp-stories

my website is based on non-amp pages and now I have developed and amp page and amp story for each non-amp page, how should reference the pages?

I have tried using two "rel=canonical" but I got error in google search console and when adding two AMPHTML link google stopped showing my amp in search results.

How could I reference my amphtml and amp story in my none-amp page and how should i refrence my pages in AMP pages ?

How could I reference my amphtml and amp story in my none-amp page and how should i refrence my pages in AMP pages ?

Answer (score 1):

For non story AMP pages you can use this rel=canonical pattern you've been mentioning:

> Add the following to the non-AMP page:
>
> `<link rel="amphtml" href="https://www.example.com/url/to/amp/document.html">`
>
> And this to
>   the AMP page:
>
> `<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/url/to/full/document.html">`

For AMP Stories it's a bit different, they are "self canonical" and have to link to themselves. You cannot have a non-AMP Story linked to an AMP Story.

The canonical link needs to point to itself:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/url/to/amp/document.html">
```